# SCC: why are there 2 SQL files?

Tags: stellar-core

The [SCC](https://github.com/stellar/stellar_core_commander) (Stellar Core Commander) is a tool used to generate a "state" for Horizon's tests. When I run it against an .rb script, it generates a *single* .sql file - essentially a 'pg_dump' of the sql database that's used by the tool.

However, the example files given in https://github.com/stellar/go/tree/master/services/horizon/internal/test/scenarios have 2 .sql files for every .rb script - one designated as 'core' and another designated as 'horizon'.

why are there 2 files?
what do I need them for?
how do I generate them?

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out: I'm using scc incorrectly. When run manually, scc does generate just a single .sql file for every .rb file. However, the intended use for scc **isn't** to be run manually, but rather to be run as part of the ./services/horizon/internal/scripts/build_test_scenarios.bash script, which among other things, runs scc. The two .sql files are created by this bash script.

so this explains how the files are created but not what they are for. I suspect some test scenarios require only stellar-core core while others require both stellar-core and horizon, and hence the 2 files